# How to get Ok message from fs::copy in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get my head around rust and I'm trying simple stuff. I want to copy a file from a certain location to another location but I also want to include an "this operation went fine" message if the copy command went well but I cannot get this working. I've tried the following link:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.copy.html
I'm trying to implement following link (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/ ) but I'm stuck and each time I try something the compiler says no

```
use std::fs;
use std::fs::copy;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let source = "c:\\Aerocom\\win3000\\win3000.log";
    let destination = "w:\\win3000r.log";
    println!("C\\Aerocom\\win3000\\bestaat: {}",Path::new(source).exists());
    println!("w:\\win3000r.log bestaat: {}",Path::new(destination).exists());
    fs::copy(source,destination)
      .expect("f* while copy");

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Put `println!("this operation went fine");` at the end. It won't be reached if the operation failed and `expect` caused a panic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the program gets to the end without panicking then it went fine!

If you want to handle the two cases explicitly, you can use a pattern match:

```
match fs::copy(source, destination) {
    Ok(_) => println!("it worked!"),
    Err(e) => panic!("Failed with error: {e:?}")
}
```

Comment: Great, many thanks. It's just for learning purposes I wanted this to work and this is another (really small) step :)